# Is it better to create your sharepoint application in sharepoint designer or visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I have been asked to create a sandboxed SharePoint application/site; multiple developers will be working on this. All the team members are .Net developers. Which is the best/maintainable/professional approach?

Approach 1 - Create pages, lists, workflows etc. in SharePoint and SharePoint designer. Then export the wsp file and import it into visual studio. e.g. do most of the work in the SharePoint ui.

Approach 2 - Build it up using visual studio e.g. modules, elements, feature receivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how much you want to do with the sharepoint application.

Sharepoint Designer has slightly more functionality than the SPS web admin interface, and this connects directly to your SPS instance.

VS will give you far more flixibility but requires greater programming knowledge and (if memory serves me) you will require an instance of SPS installed on your development machine.

Comment: Correct, if you use Visual Studio, you will need a SharePoint instance running on the same machine. However, you should not run Visual Studio in a SharePoint production environment.